# Declaring C++ static member functions as friends of the class in which it resides (syntax)

Tags: c++, syntax, friend, static-members

What is the syntax for declaring a static member function as a `friend` of the class in which it resides.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  static void Callback(void* thisptr); //Declare static member
  friend static void Callback(void* thisptr); //Define as friend of itself
}
```

**Can I fold it into this one-liner?**

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  friend static void Callback(void* thisptr); //Declare AND Define as friend
}
```

Is there another way to fold it all into a single line?

### Answer

Please don't downvote, this stems from my lack of knowledge about C++ static member functions. The answer is that they don't need to be **friend**, they already can access private members. So my question was somewhat invalid.

Comment: No need to use static if it is friend.

Comment: @AVD then it cannot be called by C. That's the reason it's static in the first place.

Comment: @unixmax83: it can't be called by C anyway because it also needs to be declared extern "C". Although most compiler allow calling a functions without this from C and it even works, it isn't portable and there are system which have different calling conventions for C and C++ functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, no need to use friend if it is static is more accurate. A static member function has access to the internals of the class just like a normal member function. The only difference is it doesn't have a this pointer.

```
void MyClass::Callback(void* thisptr) {
    MyClass* p = static_cast<MyClass*>(thisptr);
    p->public_func(); // legal
    p->private_func(); // legal
    p->private_int_var = 0; // legal
}
```

Comment: I was using `reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>` thanks for correcting me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with reinterpret_cast here. Casting from void*, static_cast and reinterpret_cast should produce identical code based on most common C++ implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The class member function cannot be a friend of its own class - its already the class member and can access its privates. What' the point in befriending it? Its not Facebook...

Answer (score 2):

A static member function has access to the `protected` / `private` parts of a class by default, no need to make it a `friend`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
  Foo(int i) : an_int(i) {}

  static void print_an_int(Foo& self){
    std::cout << self.an_int;
  }
private:
  int an_int;
};

int main(){
  Foo f(5);
  Foo::print_an_int(f); // output: 5
}
```

Comment: Just to point out: the function being static is entirely irrelevant. **Any** class member function can access the class private/protected parts.

Comment: @littleadv: That's pretty obvious, the OP's misunderstanding seemed to be exactly this, that static member functions aren't treated any differently than normal member function w.r.t. access checking.

Comment: not the answer I was looking for. jmucchiello shows an example with a pointer, your answer is by reference.

Comment: @unixman: Erm... that doesn't matter in any way, the concept is still the same. Static class member -> has access to protected/private content.